# Can I add a delay between consequent generations of cell in collection view and animate each

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, delay, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view and I wish to animate each cell in it in a way that each cell appears on screen 2 seconds after the previous one did. can this be achieved in a simple way like by adding delay?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    GalleryCell *cell = (GalleryCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"identifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];   
    cell.alpha = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
        cell.alpha = 1;
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have tried this. It hides and shows the entire collection , I want it to happen cell wise...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: if your data structure is called `items`, create a new array called `displayedItems` and use this one instead for your `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods.

Now, your `displayedItems` array should be initially empty, and you should fill it one item at a time. You can do this by using `[self performSelector:@selector(insertElement) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2]`.

Your `insertElement` method should look like this:

```
- (void)insertElement {
    /*
        you could just use an index instead of duplicating the array,
        but this way gives you additional flexibility
    */

    int indexToInsert = self.displayedItems.count
    Element *elementToInsert = self.items[indexToInsert];
    [self.displayedItems addObject:elementToInsert];
    [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToInsert inSection:0]]];

    if(self.displayedItems.count < self.items.count) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(insertElement) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
    }
}
```

If you want your `UICollectionViewCells` to appear with an animation, you can read [this](https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/collectionview-animations/).

Comment: This seems okay but the array that you mention should contain cells right? UICollectionViewCells

Comment: No, it should contain your data objects. For example, if you want to display colors in your collection view, then your data array will probably need to contain UIColor objects.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer and explanation. In my case though i have a custom cell that needs to be put into the collection not an element. Does this mean I have to create an array of the custom cell? And when you say instead of collection view data source methods you mean i should not implement any of them in my file?

Comment: You don't want to have an array of cells. You need to implement the usual methods of uicollectionviewdatasource (numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAtIndexPath at least). In cellForItemAtIndexPath you will need to create or dequeue a reusable cell, but you should not keep a reference to it... Just return it and the collectionView will draw it.

Comment: When i said "use this one instead for your dataSource methods", i meant that, for instance, in numberOfItemsInSection, instead of returning items.count, you should return displayedItems.count